# Regarding chaining single function

Tags: javascript, closures, method-chaining

I came across one question where we are expected to write a JS function 'func' which is suppose to behave as given below

```
func("world") --> returns --> hiworld
func()("world") --> returns --> hiiworld
func()()("world") --> returns --> hiiiworld
func()()()("world") --> returns --> hiiiiworld
func()()()()("world") --> returns --> hiiiiiworld
func()()()()()("world") --> returns --> hiiiiiiworld
```

So, it has to be callable and we need to add 'i' between **hi** and **world** depending upon the number of times it is called. I was able to write the code as given below:-

```
function parent () {
    let mid = '' 
    function func(param) {
        if(param) {
            let str = 'hi' + mid + param
            mid = ''
            return str
        }
        
        mid += 'i'
        
        return func
    }
    
    return func
}


let func = parent()
```

But I was unable to meet the test case:-

```
func() --> returns func
func()("world") --> returns --> hiiworld
```

We are not suppose to define **func** variable again. Basically we need a way to track number of times func is called when invoked in chaining mechanism. New call should count from start. Can anybody pitch in and throw some ideas regarding how can we achieve this behavior?

Comment: What is the expected output for func() ?

Comment: It has to be string if the last parameter of the function is string. For no parameter, it has to be that function only

Comment: check out @JohnOyegbite's answer, im pretty sure it is perfect for what you wanted

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code you need, see the explanation below.

```
const func = (param = "") => {
    const inner = (word = "") => {
        if (word.length === 0) {
            inc += 1;
            return inner;
        }
        return "hi" + ("i".repeat(inc)) + word;
    }

    if (param.length !== 0) {
        return "hiworld";
    }

    let inc = 1;

    return inner;
}
```

This alternative below would as well give the same output

```
const func = (param="") => {

    if (param.length !== 0) {
         return "hiworld";
    }

    let inc = 1;

    const inner = (word="") => {
        if (word.length === 0) {
            inc += 1;            
            return inner;
        }
        return "hi" + ("i".repeat(inc)) + word;
    }
    
    return inner;
}
```

- `func("world")`: We would execute from **line 1** and stop at **line 12**. And since **param** is **"world"** we would just return **"hiworld"**
- `func()("world")`: Now param is not passed in (the first part of the call `func()`) so line **10** to **12** would be skipped,
  `innec.inc` would be **1** on **line 14** then we return the `inner` function to `func()`. Now that the **inner** is now returned to `func()` and called with argument **"world"**.
  i.e `func()` would return `inner` and we now say `inner("world")` (this is equivalent to `func()("world")` where the first part `func() == inner)`. Which means that **word** is **"world"** since it is argument of **inner**. **Line 3 to 6** won't be executed so we return `"hiiworld"`. ``` inner.inc``"i" ``` means duplicating `"i"` `inner.inc` number of times which is just once for now.
- `func()()("world")`: The **1st** part `func()` returns `inner` (`inner.inc` is currently `1`). The **2nd** part `func()()` returns `inner` then calls `inner` with and empty argument. i.e **word** would be an empty string and **line 3 to 6** would now be executed incrementing **inner.inc** to **2** and returning `inner` again, also neglecting **line 7**. The **3rd** part: since the **2nd** part has incremented **inner.inc** and also returned `inner`, then we use the `inner` returned and call the argument **"world"** on it. which **word** would now be **"world"** and **line 3 to 6** is now skipped and **line 7** returns `"hiiiworld"`. Note that `inner.inc` is now **2**.

This goes on and on.. The idea is that **inner.inc** would keep getting incremented on **line 4** as long as we don't supply the argument **word**. The moment we supply the argument, then **line 7** is now executed and we are done.

Here is the Python equivalent if needed

```py
def func(param=""):
    if param:
        return "hiworld"

    def inner(word=""):
        if word:
            inner.inc += 1
            return inner
        return "hi" + inner.inc * "i" + word
       
    inner.inc = 1
    return inner
```